# How do I link to a pdf using CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, hyperlink, download

this is such a simple task, yet I can't seem to get it to load a pdf.

I have a simple link on my view that links to a pdf stored in a downloads folder.

Is there something I'm missing about doing this in CodeIgniter?

```
<div class="node_title_grant">
  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/downloads/grant.pdf" target="_blank">
    Grant
  </a>
</div>
```

then I have grant.pdf stored in a downloads folder in my application folder.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the normal path ...

```
href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/downloads/grant.pdf"
```

Or:

```
href="/application/downloads/grant.pdf"
```

Edit:

I believe .htaccess was the problem. Moving the downloads folder from inside applications to the root directory solved the issue.

Comment: I afraid either of those worked. I even added "/application" to my existing path which seemed correct.

Comment: yes, in my systems folder and all it has in it is "deny from all"

Comment: Is your site live anywhere? I'd like to see what links it's outputting

Comment: echo out what `<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/downloads/grant.pdf` does, tell me. Try it in your browser to to see if it works. Also - is there a .htaccess in your application folder? There is in mine and it has Deny from all ... Try moving your download folder to the root (one above application), and then accessing it via /downloads/grant.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`anchor`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function here:

```
<div class="node_title_grant">
    <?php echo anchor('downloads/grant.pdf', 'Grant', 'target="_blank"); ?>
</div>
```

Or, you can pass the filename to [`base_url`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html):

```
<div class="node_title_grant">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('downloads/grant.pdf');?>" target="_blank">
        Grant
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: getting the same 404 page not found error after trying both of these options. I am certain that my path is correct and the file is on my server.

Comment: have you compared the generated URL - and tried to access the file directly? This is not a CI problem - its just a simple address issue

Comment: How would you suggest I try to access it?